# Conditional Databinding in Xamarin.iOS using MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Here is the scenario/dilemma I'm currently in.

I have a UIImageView that contains a placeholder Image.

```
myImageView = new MvxImageView
{
 Image = ImagePlaceHolder
};
```

I bind a MvxImageViewLoader from the View to a string property(URL)in the ViewModel.

```
imageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => myImageView);
```

All of this works just fine and properly displays the image when a valid URL is present.

The issue is this, Say the bound URL/imageLoader does not contain a string.

Instead of defaulting back to the placeholder image, I would like to display a UILabel in Place of the Image View.

Whereby this UILabel, will also be bound to some text.

....

Now that I think about it, I believe a possible solution would be to create a boolean property on the ViewModel and have its status update depending on the value of the URL i.e

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(URL).
```

Then I could have the UILabel's.Hidden property bounded to this boolean property in the ViewModel to determine whether or not to show or hide the Label.

Not sure If I should delete this or let it be... it may be helpful to someone in the future.

.. I guess sometimes its best to talk it out... even if you're typing it out.